# How to track RIP/EIP (Instruction pointer) value while debugging

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-64, x64dbg

While debugging, when a debugger hits, the value of RIP register is the current address where debugger was attached. But, Is there a way to know previous value of RIP/EIP register, so that it would be clear what opcode executed before that current opcode?

Comment: Unless you have some kind of tracing / logging, e.g. possibly via a CPU feature like Last Branch Record (LBR), then no.  I'm not sure if LBR info is there for a debugger to read if it wasn't already attached earlier to enable it before running to a breakpoint or fault.

Comment: In general, no, but what we typically do is single step from some known point forward, then we can see the instruction stream that reaches somewhere thereafter.  Otherwise divide & conquer to find the known point from which to step forward.  Of course, some simulators will support back stepping.

Comment: Thanks I thought so. I was thinking there may be an alternated register or something that could hold previous RIP/EIP value, but I guess such feature was never included.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you mean like Intel's Branch Trace technique (BTS)? Or is the debugger related only?

Comment: x64dbg has a [tracing feature](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/gui/views/Trace.html).